# Tensorflow Tensor to evaluate able string

Tags: python, tensorflow, eval

Is there a function in TensorFlow or an other way, that I can make a string off a tensor and than  create a identical tensor out off that string with a function like `eval`? To use `eval` I would need the string to be in a shape like this:`'tf.Variable(np.array[1,2,3], shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int64)'` I've tried to make a class that formats the string representation of the tensor like that, but it sometimes fail and I don't now why. That's my class:

```
class TensorDecoder:
    def __init__(self, tensor):
        self.tensor = tensor

    def decodeDtype(self, strDtype):
        strDtype = strDtype.split("'")[1]
        strDtype = 'tf.' + strDtype

        return strDtype

    def __repr__(self):
        tValue = str(self.tensor.numpy().tolist())
        dtype = self.decodeDtype(str(self.tensor.dtype))
        shape = str(self.tensor.shape)

        return f'tf.Variable({tValue}, dtype={dtype}, shape={shape})'
```

I think a function of TensorFlow would be a better option, but may be you can see a mistake, that causes that the string ends up like this: `<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(6,) dtype=float64, numpy=\narray([262.82998657, 262.82998657, 262.82998657,\n262.82998657,\n262.82998657,   0.        ])>`

Comment: Maybe the string has been messed up of an other part of the program, I'm not sure. Because of that I would prefer a function of TensorFlow so I can debug if it don't works.

Comment: You don't have a `numpy` attribute in your return string. Do you have the latest version of your TensorDecoder? + I couldn't replicate the issue. It worked fine in TF 2.1